# bufferewd reader spacing string

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I have the following code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String fichier = "achats.txt";

try{
    InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(fichier);
    InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
    String ligne;

    while((ligne=br.readLine())!=null){
        builder.append(ligne);
    }

    br.close();
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

My file text achats is

> Jean Boucher, 32134564, 543, 54
>   Gilles Boucher, 32145425, 555, 21

I have the following problem: After I read it from the file it appears to me like this:

> J e a n  B o u c h e r , 3 2 1 3 4 5 6 4, 5 4 3 , 5 4

I try to do remove all white space but still remains the same. I don't really care what it looks like on my screeen. but I need the numbers 543 and 555 without spaces so I can  convert them from string to int. Does somebody has any hint how to make it clean after reading it?

Comment: You're currently using the system default encoding, and I suspect that's the problem. What's the *actual* encoding of the file? My guess is that it's UTF-16.#

Comment: (I would add an answer, but there's not much point until you've confirmed the encoding of the file.)

Comment: my encoding is Iso-8859-1 for my xml file (yes i have this too). and for .txt file it's encoding is ansi (i don't know how to change it to iso-8859-1 since it's not into txt save encoding)

Comment: i have change my ansi to utf-8 and now it's work properly.

Answer (score -1):

It's happening because your file contains data of size 1 byte, but the reader class is for reading characters rather than bytes and uses 2 bytes for each character read from file. You have to use InputStream classes rather than InputReader classes.

```
StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
           String fichier="achats.txt";
           byte [] ar = new byte[1];
           try{
               InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(fichier);
               BufferedInputStream br=new BufferedInputStream(ipsr);
               ar[0] = -1;
               while((ar[0] = br.read()) != -1){
                    builder.append(new String(ar[0]));
                }
                ips.close();
                br.close();
               }
             catch (Exception e){
             System.out.println(e.toString());
               }
```

Comment: You're assuming that each character is a single byte, and you're still effectively using the system default encoding. This is *not* the way to fix the issue.

Comment: The correct way is to open the file using the correct encoding, but still using a reader. It's *text* data, not binary data, so the OP *does* want to use a `Reader` rather than an `InputStream` directly... but they need to do so with the right encoding.

Comment: No, because we don't know the encoding of the file - read my comments on the question. But this approach is *not* the right one.

Comment: Your claims about readers always reading 2 bytes for each character are incorrect, too - in fact, the problem here is that the reader is reading *one* byte for each character, but the OP's file contains *two* bytes for each character. Your way round would only be correct if the OP's output omitted every other character.